# How many solutions exist for a non-linear system

Tags: contest-math, nonlinear-system

How many solutions exist to the following system:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
xy+xz &=& 54+x^2 \\
yx+yz &=& 64+y^2  \\
xz+yz &=&  70+z^2
\end{eqnarray}
$$

I have guessed that the solutions, if exist, have to be integer, then we get:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
x(y+z-x) &=& 2\cdot 3\cdot 3\cdot 3 \\
y(x+z-y) &=& 2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2\cdot2  \\
z(x+y-z) &=&  2\cdot5\cdot7
\end{eqnarray}
$$

Looking at the third equation, there are 8 possibilities for the value of $z$ and the situation is much worse for the other two equations.

My questions are:

- is my guess about the solutions is correct, and how one can prove it?
- how to proceed without exhaustive testing for each of the possibilities?
- is there a better way to approach this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether helpful, but use Cyclic Sum(x - y - z)^2 = Cyclic Sum(x - y)^2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly as you had factorized:

$x(y+z-x) = 54$.

$y(z+x-y) = 64$.

$z(x+y-z) = 70$.

Also the differences between equations are:

$(x-y)z = (x-y)(x+y) - 10$.

$(y-z)x = (y-z)(y+z) - 6$.

$(x-z)y = (x-z)(x+z) - 16$.

Which are equivalent to:

$(x-y)(x+y-z) = 10$.

$(y-z)(y+z-x) = 6$.

$(x-z)(z+x-y) = 16$.

And combining with the factorizations gives:

$\frac{x-y}{z} = \frac{10}{70}$.

$\frac{y-z}{x} = \frac{6}{54}$.

$\frac{x-z}{y} = \frac{16}{64}$.

You can already easily guess an answer at this point: $7,8,9$.

But continuing we can always scale $(x,y,z)$ so that $z = 7$ and so:

$x-y = 1$ and $9(y-7) = x$.

Whence you get the scaled solution and unscale to get the 'general' solution.

It turns out that only the two obvious integer triples satisfy the original.

Comment: Nice  +1 for the solution

Comment: @Shailesh: Thanks! I was pleasantly surprised that things cancelled out so nicely.

Comment: Thx, very nice indeed!